# Connection between python and firebase not established

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from firebase using python but Im getting many errors. This is my code-

```
    from firebase import firebase
    firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://pythonconnection-7b738.firebaseio.com/')
    result = firebase.get('/users', None)
    print(result)
```

One of the errors are:

> File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\firebase\firebase.py", line 38, in make_get_request response = connection.get(url, params=params,headers=headers,timeout=timeout)

Comment: post the errors, seems like, missing basic listeners and calls

Comment: One of the errors are:
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\firebase\firebase.py", line 38, in make_get_request
response = connection.get(url, params=params,headers=headers,timeout=timeout)

Comment: @Shruti edit your question and put your errors there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have the SDK:

`$ sudo pip install firebase-admin`

2. Make sure you include it and setup properly:

`import firebase_admin from firebase_admin import credentials`

`cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json') default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)`

Comment: don't use `sudo` if you are using `virtualenv`